# Add SqlTrackingService for xamlx workflow

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, tracking

I designed a workflow service (xamlx) and I want  to track it, using for instance SqlTrackingService. As the process is defined in xamlx file, I can't add

```
WorkflowRuntime wRuntime = new WorkflowRuntime();
wRuntime.AddService(new SqlTrackingService(connectionString));
wRuntime.StartRuntime();
```

beacause there's nowhere to put it... How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are working on. You are referring to XAMLX workflow services which is a WF4 concept. But the code is using a WorkflowRuntime and SqlTrackingService which are WF3 artifacts. And WF3 and WF4 are two very different and independent things that don't really mix.